# How to get userInfo when user click in notification when app is closed?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm doing an app that schedule local notifications and save an userInfo. That's part its ok.

But when app is closed, Notification appear, but when user click, the method is not called and I can't handle userInfo.

I saw that there's a new way to receive notification with `UNUserNotificationCenter`. But is not working too.

That's my implementation in AppDelegate:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let lNotification = UILocalNotification()
    lNotification.userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    applicationWorker.manage(localNotification: lNotification)
}
```

Anyone to help me? I saw all the questions related here and didn't found anything.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

If someone are looking for a solution, I added `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and it worked.

Comment: @MarcusMenezes I added `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then method was called. I Hope it helps!!

Comment: tks @rafaela-lourenço

Comment: @RafaelaLourenço I’m glad you got it working by setting the delegate. That would explain why the method wasn’t getting called! :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From iOS 10 onwards, the method you mention should be called whether app is opening from background or inactive state. Perhaps you are not accessing the userInfo correctly. The example below works for me.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let yourData = userInfo["yourKey"] as? String {
        // Handle your data here, pass it to a view controller etc.
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**: as per the edit to the question, the notification centre delegate must be set in the `didFinishLaunching()` method, or the method above will not get called.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

Comment: But my app doesn't enter in this function when closed.. I don't know why.. There's another configuration to make it happen?

Comment: It will call when you open app by clicking notification

Comment: Is it possible that your iOS version check is not working correctly? You can leave it out unless targeting below iOS 10.

Comment: Try inserting a print() statement at the start of the method to check if it is being called. The problem could be the other bits of code, which might make it appear that the method is not being called. As noted by @vp2698 the user must tap the notification and then the app will open and this method should be called.

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work for me. When app is closed, I can't get userInfo when launch (touching in notification).

Answer (score 0):

You can got the notification user info from launch option when application open from notification. Here is the code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

   if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                if let aps = notification["aps"] as? NSDictionary
                    {

                    }
            }
}
```

Comment: I think this is deprecated, no?

Comment: No it is working you can still got the info from launch option, try once

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work for me. When app is closed, I can't get userInfo when launch (touching in notification).